# PHP - PHPUnit - Handle fails inside try/catch for mocked object

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, try-catch, assertion

I have the issues when an assertion fails is caught by the testing code "try-catch" block, giving the result false test result.

The be more precise I created a piece of code to reproduce the issue:

**TestUnit.php**

```
namespace MyNamespace;

class TestUnit
{
    private $service = null;

    public function setDependency($service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function test($data)
    {
        $data++;
        try {
            $this->service->save($data);
            return 1;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Here we catch that we cannot save
        }
    }
}
```

**ServiceDependency.php**

```
namespace MyNamespace;

class ServiceDependency
{
    public function save($item)
    {
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

**TestUnitTest.php**

```
namespace MyNamespace;

class TestUnitTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testMethod()
    {
        $mydata = 5;
        $expectedData = 7;

        $testUnit = new TestUnit();
        $dependentService = $this->createMock(ServiceDependency::class);
        $dependentService->expects($this->any())
            ->method('save')
            ->will($this->returnCallback(function($data) use($expectedData) {
                var_dump($data == $expectedData);
                $this->assertEquals($data, $expectedData, "This should fail!");
                $this->assertTrue(false, "This should fail also!");
            }));
        $testUnit->setDependency($dependentService);
        $testUnit->test($mydata);
    }
}
```

The test restul runned:

> PHPUnit 5.6.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> 1 / 1 (100%)/--path--/TestUnitTest.php:16:
>
> bool(false)
>
> Time: 211 ms, Memory: 10.00MB
>
> OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

What really happens here is that an assertion throws a **PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException** that is caught by TestUnit::test() try/catch block.

How can I bypass this kind of issues?

Comment: seems the assertion is ignored inside the `returnCallback` statement. Try moving the var_dump after the first assertion that should fail and nothing will be printed BUT no failed assertion is computed. You should change the testing strategy i suppose....

Comment: Even if I force it to do the asertion (by try catching the asertion block, it would not fail). The failed assertion result is an exception leading to hard-to-test block of code. Any code that contains a try/catch error handling leads to catch the failed assertion... I will try to further dig in this situation but is clearly that a test design is more complex for this kind of code...

Comment: technically there is a way to bypass the issue you've mentioned -- by filtering `$e` in catch block in `test` method of `TestUnit` and rethrowing an exception if needed (that's because you force PHPUnit exception to be thrown from prodction code -- you do it in callback). but you surely won't like such a decision beacuse it will make your production code dependent on test code. So changing you testing strategy is a far better way to go just as @Matteo said. What behavior are you trying to test? Currently it doesn't really test anything.

Comment: This is just a dummy example. The "master" code is far more complex and different from the one presented but with a test scenario like this one, were the dependent object is surrounded by a try catch...

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem trying to test some methods that should fire events.
I'm mocking an event dispatcher/handler/obsever/[insert name here] class that is wrapped in a try & catch from the caller.

To get around the problem I created a trait (as I use it in multiple test classes) who's job is to store the results and assert them once outside the try and catch.

In my example I'm checking the events are called in the correct order. (Code has been simplified for clarity)

```php
trait EventStackTrait
{
    protected $expectedEventStack = [];

    protected $actualEventStack = [];

    /**
     * Check the correct events are called
     * @param array $eventStack expected events in order
     * @return void
     */
    protected function createMockEventHandlerWithStack( array $eventStack )
    {
        $this->expectedEventStack = $eventStack;
        $this->actualEventStack = [];

        $event = $this->createMock( \Event::class );

        $event->expects( $this->any() )
              ->method( 'dispatch' )
              ->with(
                  $this->callback( function ( $subject )
                  {
                      $this->actualEventStack[] = $subject;
                      return true;
                  }
                  )
              )
              ->will( $this->returnValue( true ) );
    }

    protected function assertAllEventsWhereCalled( ?string $message = null )
    {
        $this->assertEquals( $this->expectedEventStack, $this->actualCallerStack, 'Events not as expected' );
    }
}
```

Then in the test class

```php
class FoobarTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    use EventStackTrait;

    public function testAddFromArrayFiresEvents()
    {
        $this->createMockEventHandlerWithStack(
            [
                BeforeCreate::EVENT,
                Created::EVENT,
            ]
        );

        $foobar = new \Foobar();
        $foobar->addFromArray( [ .... ] );

        $this->assertAllEventsWhereCalled();
    }
}
```

(Note I'm fairly new to unit test, so there's probably a better way)